ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row for OTBI SQL
While creating a SQL query to extract Purchase Order information, the subquery to retrieve item number afiliated with the Purchase order returns the following error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.
Below is the full SQL query:
SELECT
     distinct item.item_number              item_number

FROM
     po_headers_all pha
    ,fun_all_business_units_v fav
    ,po_buyers_val_v pbv_inner
    ,poz_suppliers_v psv
    ,po_lines_all pla
    ,egp_categories_vl egp
    ,hr_locations_all hla
    ,hr_locations_all hla2
    ,po_distributions_all pda
    ,po_line_locations_all plla
    ,gl_code_combinations gcc
    ,pjf_tasks_v pt
    ,poz_supplier_sites_all_m pss
    ,hr_organization_units hru
    ,(select pjf.name,pb.segment1,pb.project_id
      from pjf_projects_all_b pb, pjf_projects_all_tl pjf
      where  pjf.project_id = pb.project_id)
      project
    ,(select pha2.segment1 ,pla2.line_num, pla2.po_line_id,pha2.po_header_id
      from po_headers_all pha2 ,po_lines_all pla2
      where  pha2.po_header_id = pla2.po_header_id  
      and pha2.type_lookup_code(+) = 'BLANKET')
      agreement
    ,(select esiav.item_number,esiav.inventory_item_id
      FROM egp_system_items_b esiav,inv_org_parameters IOP
      WHERE ESIAV.organization_id = IOP.organization_id 
      AND IOP.organization_code='WSH_ITEMMSTR')
      item  
     /* Old logic- requisition number not getting populated 
            ,(select 
        prh.requisition_number
        ,prl.po_header_id
        ,prl.req_bu_id
        ,prl.po_line_id
        ,pf.full_name
        from 
        por_requisition_lines_all prl
        ,por_requisition_headers_all prh
        ,PER_PERSON_NAMES_F pf
        where
        prl.requisition_header_id = prh.requisition_header_id
        AND prl.requester_id= pf.person_id(+)
        AND pf.name_type='GLOBAL')
      rq */
WHERE 1=1
    and pha.po_header_id           = pla.po_header_id
    and pha.po_header_id           = pda.po_header_id (+)
    and pha.agent_id               = pbv_inner.person_id
    and pha.vendor_id              = psv.vendor_id
    and plla.ship_to_location_id   = hla.location_id(+) 
    and pha.req_bu_id              = fav.bu_id(+)
    and pha.vendor_site_id         = pss.vendor_site_id
    and pla.po_line_id             = pda.po_line_id(+)
    and pla.item_id                = item.inventory_item_id(+)
    and pla.category_id            = egp.category_id     
    and pla.po_line_id             = plla.po_line_id
    and pla.from_header_id         = agreement.po_header_id(+)  
    and pla.from_line_id           = agreement.po_line_id(+)
    and pda.deliver_to_location_id = hla2.location_id(+)  
    and pda.code_combination_id    = gcc.code_combination_id(+)
    and pda.pjc_organization_id    = hru.organization_id(+)  
    and pda.pjc_project_id         = project.project_id(+)
    and pda.pjc_task_id            = pt.task_id(+)
    and pss.vendor_id              = psv.vendor_id
        /* Old logic- requisition number not getting populated 
    and pha.po_header_id           = rq.po_header_id(+)
    and pla.req_bu_id              = rq.req_bu_id(+)
    and pla.po_line_id             = rq.po_line_id(+) */
    and pha.type_lookup_code       = 'STANDARD'
    and pha.document_status not in ('INCOMPLETE','CANCELED','REJECTED')
    and pla.line_status not in ('INCOMPLETE','CANCELLED')


I expect the ability to retrieve all items numbers afiliated with the purchase order, with minimal changes.

post CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements (or equivalent) for your sample data, so the people who want to help you can have a table exactly like yours.. In addition, show the results you expect. You should always do that whenever you post a problem.

Those nested selects aren't going to work at all. Any nested inline select within the SELECT clause requires no exactly 1 result row with 1 column. You are asking for multiple columns and apparently multiple rows, making an inline select inappropriate. Rewrite as normal joins in the FROM clause.

If I got your query's join conditions right then the code using join syntax should look like this:
--    NOT CHECKED NOR TESTED IN ANY WAY  ***
SELECT      Distinct item.item_number as item_number
FROM        po_headers_all              pha
INNER JOIN  po_buyers_val_v             pbv_inner ON( pha.agent_id = pbv_inner.person_id )
INNER JOIN  po_lines_all                pla  ON( pha.po_header_id = pla.po_header_id )
INNER JOIN  po_line_locations_all       plla ON( pla.po_line_id = plla.po_line_id )
INNER JOIN  poz_supplier_sites_all_m    pss  ON( pha.vendor_site_id = pss.vendor_site_id )
INNER JOIN  poz_suppliers_v             psv  ON( pha.vendor_id = psv.vendor_id And 
                                                 pss.vendor_id = psv.vendor_id )
INNER JOIN  egp_categories_vl           egp  ON( pla.category_id = egp.category_id )
--
LEFT  JOIN  fun_all_business_units_v    fav  ON( pha.req_bu_id = fav.bu_id )
LEFT  JOIN  po_distributions_all        pda  ON( pha.po_header_id = pda.po_header_id And 
                                                 pla.po_line_id = pda.po_line_id )
LEFT  JOIN  hr_locations_all            hla  ON( plla.ship_to_location_id = hla.location_id )
LEFT  JOIN  hr_locations_all            hla2 ON( pda.deliver_to_location_id = hla2.location_id )
LEFT  JOIN  gl_code_combinations        gcc  ON( pda.code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id )
LEFT  JOIN  pjf_tasks_v                 pt   ON( pda.pjc_task_id = pt.task_id )
LEFT  JOIN  hr_organization_units       hru  ON( pda.pjc_organization_id = hru.organization_id )
--
LEFT JOIN ( Select  pjf.name,pb.segment1, pb.project_id
            From    pjf_projects_all_b pb, pjf_projects_all_tl pjf
            Where   pjf.project_id = pb.project_id 
          ) project     ON( pda.pjc_project_id = project.project_id )
--
LEFT JOIN ( Select      pha2.segment1, pla2.line_num, pla2.po_line_id, pha2.po_header_id
            From        po_headers_all  pha2 
            Left Join   po_lines_all    pla2    ON( pha2.po_header_id = pla2.po_header_id  And 
                                                    pha2.type_lookup_code = 'BLANKET' )
          ) agreement   ON( pla.from_header_id = agreement.po_header_id And 
                            pla.from_line_id           = agreement.po_line_id )
--
LEFT JOIN ( Select      esiav.item_number, esiav.inventory_item_id
            From        egp_system_items_b esiav
            Inner Join  inv_org_parameters iop ON(  esiav.organization_id = IOP.organization_id And 
                                                    IOP.organization_code = 'WSH_ITEMMSTR' ) 
          ) item        ON( pla.item_id = item.inventory_item_id )
--
WHERE       pha.type_lookup_code = 'STANDARD' And 
            pha.document_status not in ('INCOMPLETE','CANCELED','REJECTED') And 
            pla.line_status not in ('INCOMPLETE','CANCELLED')

It looks like you are using this to filter another query - Purchase order information. If in that query you have something like:
...
purchase_order.item_number = (the above query)
...

then you get the error message from the title of this question. The error appears if the query returns more than 1 row. We can't tell if thaat is the case since there is no sample data, no expected result and we no nothing about Purchase order query.
You could try to change the condition in your Purchase order query to use IN instead of = operator
...
purchase_order.item_number IN(the above query)
...

This should eliminate the error in question which certainly doesn't mean the result is ok. You should check your actual data and code to see is there a condition that expects 1 and only 1 value. This query will almost for sure return more than 1 row.
You are selecting item_number from Left Joined subquery and it is almost certain that you will get an additional row having item_number with the value of null.
...
If you use this query to select item_number in Selection list of another query then to test it and eliminate the error add to this query FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY. This also will not solve the problem (unless the query (as is) returns 1st row with item_number and 2nd row with null value...) but at least could be a guidance for finding one.
Another way to eliminate null value row could be to add a condition to your query's where clause:
... 
And item.item_number IS NOT NULL

This could actually solve the problem if the query (as is) returns 1 row with item_number and 1 row with null value...

I receive the same message, but here is the main SQL query:
